# php find # in string with regex

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I have a php variable where I need to show #value Values as link pattern.
The code looks like this.

```
$reg_exUrl = "/\#::(.*?)/";

 // The Text you want to filter for urls
$text = "This is a #simple text from which we have to perform #regex    operation";

// Check if there is a url in the text
   if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {

   // make the urls hyper links
    echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" rel="nofollow">'.$url[0].'</a>', $text);

   } else {

   // if no urls in the text just return the text
     echo "IN Else #$".$text;

 }
```

Comment: Code runs. I am uncertain what you want. Could you please give us some test data and describe your expected output. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you show an example and the expected output?

Comment: You tagged regex-negation, what are you trying to negate? Where are you trying to match a URL? If you want the captured value you should be using `$url[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$reg_exUrl = "/\#::(.*?)/";`

This doesn't match because of the following reasons

**1.** there is no need to escape `#`, this is because it is not  a special character.

**2.** since you want to match just `#` followed by some words, there is no need for `::`

**3.** `(.*?)` tries to match the least possible word because of the quantifier `?`. So it won't match the required length of word you need.

If you still want to go by your pattern, you can modify it to

`$reg_exUrl = "/#(.*?)\w+/"` See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lX5lX7/6)

But a more efficient one that still works is

`$reg_exUrl = "/#\w+/"`. see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lX5lX7/8)

Comment: it worked for me.
if you can tell me about detect the full URL in PHP.
I tried "^http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$" this regex but not able to detect url starts with www.

Comment: Try this  "^(? :http\://|www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$"

Answer (score 2):

By using \w, you can match a word contains alphanumeric characters and underscore. Change your expression with this:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/#(.*?)\w+/"
```

Comment: You're welcome, @ShawnMehan. Don't forget to accept as answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me exactly what you need match. If you want to replace a `#` followed by any word chars:

```
$text = "This is a #simple text from which we have to perform #regex    operation";

$reg_exUrl = "/#(\w+)/";
echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="$0" rel="nofollow">$1</a>', $text);

//Output:
//This is a <a href="#simple" rel="nofollow">simple</a> text from which we have to perform <a href="#regex" rel="nofollow">regex</a>    operation
```

The replacement uses `$0` to refer to the text matched and `$1` the first group.